# electron in the nucleus

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory

In the event that the electron is in nucleus of the atom (<strike>via tunneling effects and other things I don't understand</strike>), How does QED deal with this situation?

Answer (score 1):

> In the event that the electron is in nucleus of the atom (via tunneling effects and other things I don't understand), How does QED deal with this situation?

Solving the equations for nuclear physics with QED would be like digging a tunnel with a surgical knife. There exist nuclear models that work and describe the data, ultimately consistent with QED rules .

Look at the [orbitals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_orbitals), the locus of the state function for the electron whose square gives the probability of finding it there.

[image: orbital]

For S state solutions there exists a quantum mechanical probability for the electron to be there. If there will be a decay or not will depend on the energetics of the problem. 
There exist [electron capture decays.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_capture)

Answer (score 0):

the probability of an s-orbital electron to be at the center of the atom i.e in the nucleus is in fact non-zero. it is zero for p,d,f and higher orbitals. and the fact the probability is non-zero is why we have forbidden transitions in an atom and why we have lasers.

i don't know what you mean by the electron tunneling to the nucleus of the atom though.

Comment: To be honest I saw this tunneling thing a youtube video. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cTodS8hkSDg .  . .

Comment: Don't leave out electron capture reactions.

Comment: there is the possibility and electron might be captured by nucleus but it will not stay there and nuclear reactions will take place straightforward and and electron with some other stuff will be released, but it's not obvious yet this is the very same electron which was captured or another one which is produced. So when this is not obvious yet what happened inside nucleus what exactly do u want to know about the captured electron which includes QED?

Comment: @Negin~ Could you write an equation(Not decay equation, more some stuff with interaction terms and all) for the words you used above pls.  It's not too straightforward to me.

Comment: For at least some nuclei @Negin is simple wrong. "Electron capture" refers to reaction where a nuclear proton captures an electron turning into a neutron and a neutrino: $e^- + p^+ \to n + \nu_e$. It's not a common mode because most nuclei are neutron rich, but it does occur.

Comment: @dmckee Yes, I named the wrong reaction. but as far as I remember there was such reaction in nuclear physics, I'll put more search into it.

Comment: Negin , that would be great if you could search into it. @dmckee and I would be waiting.

Comment: for electron capture http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_capture . For S states having probability to go though the nucleus http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_orbitals

Answer (score 0):

The nucleus is a wave. As is the electron. so its just one wave going through the other. In fact this is the case with neutrinos. if you think of neutrinos as one dimensional they would pass strait through one dimensional protons.